# Accelerate batch job execution in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, parallel-processing

I'm new to batch job execution in MATLAB. I'm playing with the following code:

```
clear 
a = rand(10,1);
job = batch('l_beta');
wait(job)
load(job,'b')
```

`l_beta` is just one line of code:

```
b = sum(a);
```

While all the operations are simple, surprisingly, it took 12 seconds to execute the code in the first block. I checked out the discussion in the following link

https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/166757-why-is-batch-so-slow

It seems that there are a lot of overheads associated with starting batch jobs. I'm wondering whether there are simple ways to reduce this overhead. Say, if I do the configurations/warming-up for once and then don't need to worry about it as long as the MATLAB is running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can debug this quite easily using tic/toc and job properties. see below for an example

```
clc; close all; clear;
a = 10;

tic;
c = parcluster();
fprintf('Creating the cluster: %.2f sec\n', toc);

tic;
job = createJob(c);
fprintf('Creating a job: %.2f sec\n', toc);

tic;
createTask(job, @exp, 1, {a});
createTask(job, @sin, 1, {a});
fprintf('Creating the tasks: %.2f sec\n', toc);

tic;
submit(job);
fprintf('Submitting the job: %.2f sec\n', toc);

% Most of the time goes on scheduling the job here
% pause(10);

tic;
wait(job)
fprintf('Waiting time: %.2f sec\n', toc);

tic;
results = fetchOutputs(job);
fprintf('Fetching Results: %.2f sec\n\n', toc);

fprintf('Job Properties\n');
fprintf('Create Time: %s \n', job.CreateTime);
fprintf('Submit Time: %s \n', job.SubmitTime);
fprintf('Start Time: %s \n', job.StartTime);
fprintf('Finish Time: %s \n', job.FinishTime);

delete(job);
```

If I run this, I get the following

```
Creating the cluster: 0.01 sec
Creating a job: 0.02 sec
Creating the tasks: 0.04 sec
Submitting the job: 0.19 sec
Waiting time: 4.13 sec
Fetching Results: 0.02 sec

Job Properties
Create Time: Mon May 22 10:30:23 BST 2017 
Submit Time: Mon May 22 10:30:23 BST 2017 
Start Time: Mon May 22 10:30:26 BST 2017 
Finish Time: Mon May 22 10:30:27 BST 2017
```

You see that most of the time is lost between submission and start. the execution itself is quite fast. If you introduce a pause by removing the comment from `pause(10)`, you get the following

```
Creating the cluster: 0.01 sec
Creating a job: 0.02 sec
Creating the tasks: 0.04 sec
Submitting the job: 0.19 sec
Waiting time: 0.06 sec
Fetching Results: 0.02 sec

Job Properties
Create Time: Mon May 22 10:31:44 BST 2017 
Submit Time: Mon May 22 10:31:44 BST 2017 
Start Time: Mon May 22 10:31:47 BST 2017 
Finish Time: Mon May 22 10:31:48 BST 2017
```

Therefore, you can think of submitting the jobs early on in your code, doing some other operations while the jobs are being scheduled and run, followed by fetching the results further down your code. I hope this is helpful.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I'll check it out~